# Make the edit tags button not bump a post

Tags: feature-request, tags, editing

Four to five times a week I find my self answering a 2-3 year old question on the front page that I do not realize is a old (potentially abandoned) question that [Hennes](https://superuser.com/users/121352/hennes) edited to do tag cleanup on (Thank you for the hard work Hennes BTW!) and got bumped to the front page.

To make tag cleanup easier and faster I suggest that edits done via the new `edit tags` button (it's new to me at least, I never noticed it till a few weeks ago) do not bump a question to the front page.

Any other edit should bump it, even if you use the `edit` link and only edit tags I would be fine with that bumping the question too. I just would like it if tag edits for site cleanup where not bumping posts all of the time.

Comment: You could just [use the new questions list](http://superuser.com/questions?sort=newest) to find new questions to answer. Alternatively, the [unanswered tab](http://superuser.com/questions?sort=unanswered), or [hot questions](http://superuser.com/?tab=hot) tab might work as well.

Comment: Isn't answering an old question that needs an answer just as good as answering a new one? Perhaps better?

Answer (score 4):

That would be a great improvement. :)

NB: I do tend to edit some of the questions as well. (Mostly for clarity or to remove typos).

Answer (score 3):

I can absolutely relate to your suggestion. Seeing questions bumped for just a removed or changed tag is often annoying. That's why we tell people to do it in smaller batches rather than an entire front page's worth of posts.

And here's where the problem with allowing silent edits is: You open the door for abuse without review. Granted, we trust users with 2k reputation to make edits on their own, but we've had several cases of either 2k users approving bad tag edits (suggestions), or even making a batch of edits without community approval.

Can you imagine these edits going unnoticed because they were not bumped?

[image]

(Image courtesy of Daniel Beck, click to enlarge.)

If you propose that tag-only edits do not bump a post, we need to find a better way to just mass-edit the affected posts without having to navigate to each one separately. We do have a problem with tags and tag cleanup, but I believe the problem needs to be dealt with by making our cleanup tools more effective.